What is the analogy of frequency sampling of a 1D signal in a 2D signal (image)?
I made model to remove noise using deep learning for 1D ECG signal (time-amplitude domain). The model was trained on 360 Hz frequency sampling ECG data on millivolts unit.
I stated to my professor that my model is the robust model, that's mean it's almost compatible to any ECG raw data. But I mentioned to her there are prerequisites to my model input so that it can be preprocessed by preprocessor function first before inferred by my model.

Amplitude-axis Prerequisite: There is known amplitude unit that can be converted to mV.
Time-axis Prerequisite: There is known frequency sampling, so it can be converted to 360Hz with resampling (up sampling or down sampling depends on data).

My professor asked me, "What if an ECG signal has unknown frequency sampling?". At that time I was thinking what to say, so the conversation ended.
But here is my plan to reply her question, "I think it's impossible the frequency sampling is unknown. Since most ECG doctor might be need time info when inferring/diagnosing manually. Therefore, if there is tiny info about time for instance the duration between node A to the node B is 5 seconds and requiring 500 nodes, the preprocessor function will calculate the frequency sampling."
So, for making my argument stronger, I want to mention the analogy with another data type like image (2D signal). For example, "Not knowing frequency sampling is like not knowing the dimension of image." But I'm not sure, if the pixels is analogy with frequency sampling.

I like this question, but I don’t think your title does it justice. I would get rid of the image analogy stuff and focus on “how can I estimate the sampling rate of an ECG signal”

@Jdip estimate the sampling rate actually can be done by training new deep learning model where dataset of ECG signals have various frequency sampling is feed to the model. But, if I tell my prof about this idea, it will add burdens of my graduation. I need to graduate ASAP.

Then I would make the following point: “this model works if the sampling rate is known, which is a very minimal constraint for these types of signal where time information is essential”. That’s basically your point, I think.
